# Tokenizing a string into a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

I can't use boost (as I've seen as a solution for a lot of tokenizing questions).
First I place a typed command into a string.
Command example:

add (name, phone-number)

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    cout << "Reservations>>";
    if(line[0] == 'a'){
    }
}
```

I need to make sure everything is correct syntactically (that they used parenthesis and commas), which I was going to do by first breaking the string down into strings themselves, placed in a vector. So my first question is: How can I just break off each part separated by a space so that I can push it into the vector? I was then going to compare '(' with the string of vector[1]'s first char ([0]), and ',' with the string of vector[1]'s [line.length()] - how would I go about referencing certain characters in the string located in a vector?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c?lq=1) and the many others on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but do you know how to reference a specific character in the string located in a vector?

Comment: Are you just checking brackets balance?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).You can't use strtok directly on a C++ std::string. It requires a mutable zero-terminated C-style string, and there is no standard way to access the contents of a `std::string` in that form.

For more on this, go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628346/c-usage-of-strtok-on-string)

Comment: I tried strtok before but it won't let me pass a string as a parameter.

Comment: @WillNasby See the answers to this question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628346/c-usage-of-strtok-on-string

Comment: take a look at [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), it converts the string object to c style string

Comment: Please be aware that strtok() is not thread-safe. Use strtok_r() for threaded applications instead.